# Bootstrap carousel can't work with specific link on images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
       <div class="item active" >
          <a href='test' target='_blank'><img src="/site_media/test_image.jpg" alt="test test"></a>
          <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Test</h3>
          <p>
          </p>
          </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

Here is my code.

Carousel slider worked correctly 
and  element was showed when i inspect it
but a images can't click in mobile and ipad version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can fix this
I've added onlick function into div elements

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
   <div class="item active" onclick="window.open('test');" style="cursor: pointer;" >
       <img src="/site_media/test_image.jpg" alt="test test" />
       <div class="carousel-caption">
       <h3>Test</h3>
       <p></p>
   </div>
</div>
```